# For loop and subplots incorporation to populate histogram of different columns

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, histogram

I am tryin to draw a 2 by 19 histogram subplot of my categorical columns but the figures are empty.

df_categorical is my columns with categorical content.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(19, 2)

for col, axe in df_categorical.columns:
    plt.hist(df[col].astype(str))
    plt.xlabel(col)
plt.show()
```

This is the output that I get.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8vB4.png)

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_27/1624824132.py in <module>
      2 fig, axes = plt.subplots(19, 2)
      3 
----> 4 for col, axe in df_categorical.columns:
      5     plt.hist(df[col].astype(str))
      6     plt.xlabel(col)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

---

Comment: where is your output????

Comment: Fixed it, plus I added a photo of the plot I get. https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8vB4.png